# Yii2 advanced sorting

Tags: sorting, yii2

How can I implement the following sorting in Yii2:

```
SELECT * FROM `orders` order by case when status != 'ORDER_DONE' then 1 else 2 end,status
```

I want to drop statuses with ORDER_DONE to the bottom. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since 2.0.7 you can pass `yii\db\Expression` to `orderBy()` so do it like:

```
(new \yii\db\Query)
->from('orders')
->orderBy(new \yii\db\Expression('CASE WHEN status != "ORDER_DONE" THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, status'))
->all();
```

For sorting data provider use:

```
'sort' => [
    'attributes' => [
        'onlinedate' => [
            'asc' => [new \yii\db\Expression('CASE WHEN status != "ORDER_DONE" THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, status')],
            'desc' => [new \yii\db\Expression('CASE WHEN status = "ORDER_DONE" THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, status')],
        ],
    ],
]
```

Comment: Thanks! Can this solution somehow be used in sort attributes?

'sort' => [
 'attributes' => [
  'onlinedate' => [
   'asc' => ['onlinedate' => SORT_ASC], // need to put the status of type ORDER_DONE to bottom
   'desc' => ['onlinedate' => SORT_DESC], // need to put the status of type ORDER_DONE to top
  ],
  'status',
 ],
],

Comment: I get the following error:

Error Info: Array
(
    [0] => 42S22
    [1] => 1054
    [2] => Unknown column 'expression' in 'order clause'
)

Comment: Sorry, forgot arrays.